# Register different assembly types in autofac container in Asp.net

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, autofac

I have 3 tier architecture application. my Data Access is like below:

**ICategoryRepository.cs**

```
public interface ICategoryRepository
{
    void Add(Category category);
}
```

**CategoryRepository.cs**

```
internal class CategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository
{
    void ICategoryRepository.Add(Category category)
    {
        // Dbcontext goes here
    }
}
```

And I have a Autofac model to register the above classes in autofac container is:

```
public class RepositoryModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
               .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
               .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        base.Load(builder);
    }
}
```

And I have a service layer as below:
**ICategoryService.cs**

```
public interface ICategoryService
{
  void Add(Category category);
}
```

**CategoryService.cs**

```
internal class CategoryService : ICategoryService
{
    private ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
    public CategoryService(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository)
    { 
        _categoryRespoitory = categoryRepository;
    }
    void ICategoryService.Add(Category category)
    {
        _categoryRepository.Add(category);
    }
}
```

Similarly, I have a module to register the above class in container as,

```
public class ServiceModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
               .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
               .AsImplementedInterfaces()
               .InstancePerLifetimeScope();                        
    }
}
```

**And in my Web, Global.asax.cs:**

```
 public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication, IContainerProviderAccessor
 {
     static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

     public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
     {
         get { return _containerProvider; }
     }

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
    }
}
```

Here my question is, how can I call the service and DataAccess module from the web.

I don't have the data access reference in my web, but I have reference of service module in my web

Comment: Hey, I removed the *containers* tag and changed the *assembly* tag to *.net-assembly*. Please read the tag descriptions before using the tag! I hope now your question is found more easily by .Net experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `RegisterAssemblyModules` method

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    if (HostingEnvironment.InClientBuildManager)
    {
        assemblies = assemblies.Union(BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
                                                  .Cast<Assembly>())
                               .Distinct();
    }

    builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies);

    _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
}
```

In order to let this code works, all your assemblies should be available on the bin folder.

I use `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` to avoid issue after ASP.net recycling process. See [IIS Hosted Web Application](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html#iis-hosted-web-applications) on autofac documentation for more explanation.

Comment: Hi Cyril, Your code has worked. Thanks for replying. :)

Comment: Had to write `builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies.ToArray());`